# What is C# .Net analog for Flash/Flex flash.utils.ByteArray?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex, flash, arrays

What is the C# .Net analog for Flash/Flex `flash.utils.ByteArray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly either [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) or [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)/[`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

Comment: how than to declare FOR EX public var stream:ByteArray; IN c# ?

Comment: @Ole Jak: You wouldn't. You'd create a new BinaryWriter (or BinaryReader) wrapping an existing stream.